# add padding to a select widget

Tags: css, select, padding

How do I add padding at the top of select options text?

For example:

[image: example]

Code :

```
select {
    background-image:url(../images/select.png);
    width:287px;
    height:35px;
    text-align: center;
    border:0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:2px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#999999;
}
```

Comment: I tried added padding-top to css but the arrow also pads.

Comment: Why do you want such a tall `select` box if your font is half that height anyway?

Comment: I've other two fields 'username' and 'password' which of similar height.

Comment: did you tested on all browsers, is all browsers showing the text like?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for `line-height:35px;`. With padding you get the famous box problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
 padding-top: 10px;
height:25px;
```

to your css